# Behaviour of characters with relational operators

Tags: r, character, logical-operators

Can someone explain why R does this? And the reason behind it?

```
"-1" < 0
#[1] TRUE
# expected [1] FALSE # OR better NA

"-abc" < 0
#[1] TRUE
# expected [1] FALSE # OR better NA
```

From `?Comparison`:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw

This does not help either FWIW:

```
toString(-1) < 0
as.character(-1) < 0
toString("-abc") < 0
as.character("-abc") < 0
```

Am I wrong to expect a different result? I ask this because this seems to me something that could give unexpected results inside a function if not known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the precedence rules you already quoted:

> the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw

So in the expression:

```
"-abc" < 0
```

what is happening is that the `0` on the RHS is being coerced to character.  This leaves us with:

```
"-abc" < "0"
```

This is lexicographically true (you may check for yourself).  So the expression evaluates to true.  Note that if the coercion had gone the other way, namely if R had tried to coerce `"-abc"` to a numeric type, then it would have resulted in `NA`, and the entire expression would have evaluated to `NA`, *not* true:

```
"-abc" < 0
NA < 0
NA
```

So, this is how we know that R is coercing the RHS to character.

A good rule of thumb in R (or SQL, Java, JavaScript, really any language) is to not mess around with types.  If you know your data is numeric, then work with a numeric type and treat it as such, as vice-versa for character data.